# I don't know why this Rock, Paper, Scissors game won't work

Tags: ruby

I don't know what is wrong with this game:

```
print "Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!"
print "
All outcomes are randomly generated and independent from your answer."
puts "

Rock, paper, scissors:"
answer = gets.chomp!
answer.capitalize!

cpu = 3

if cpu == 1
  cpu = "Rock"
end

if cpu == 2
  cpu = "Paper"
end

if cpu == 3
  cpu = "Scissors"
end

print "
Your answer: #{answer}
CPU answer: #{cpu}"

if cpu == answer
  print "
  Winner: It's a tie"
end

if answer = "Rock" && cpu = "Paper"
  print  "
  Winner: CPU"
end

if answer = "Rock" && cpu = "Scissors"
  print "
  Winner: Human"
end
```

It outputs all possible answers at the end, for example:

```
Your answer: Rock
CPU answer: Scissors
  Winner: CPU
  Winner: Human
```

Comment: in your two last `if`s you are assigning values with `=`, not comparing them with `==`

Comment: I find it really hard to recognize these multiline `print` and `puts` statements.

Comment: "I am fairly new to Ruby and I don't know what is wrong with this game" - now is a perfect time for you to pick up a few debugging tricks. Will make you much more autonomous and not like fish out of the water. I use many tricks from this [blurgh post](https://tenderlovemaking.com/2016/02/05/i-am-a-puts-debuggerer.html).

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Seems to be working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Near the end of your code, there are several places where you accidentally used the assignment operator (`=`) instead of the equality checking operator (`==`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more Ruby-like way to address your problem.

```
WINS = { "rock"=>"scissors", "paper"=>"rock", "scissors"=>"paper" }

def outcome(first, second)
  return :WIN  if WINS[first]  == second
  return :LOSE if WINS[second] == first
  :TIE
end

outcome("rock", "scissors") #=> :WIN
outcome("rock", "paper")    #=> :LOSE
outcome("rock", "rock")     #=> :TIE
```

Answer (score -2):

Alexander,

The are two errors in the end of your code.

In the `if` condition replace = to ==.

```
if answer == "Rock" && cpu = "Paper"
  print  "
  Winner: CPU"
end

if answer == "Rock" && cpu = "Scissors"
  print "
  Winner: Human"
end
```